# perl one-liner replace space into under score with-in double quto

Tags: perl

I have line this, I want to replace spaces with-in the quot with underscore.

```
"Hello How are you"  Mr. John
```

with

```
"Hello_How_are_you"  Mr. John
```

I like to have the perl one-liner for this.

Thanks
SR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried anything? It helps to post what you've tried when you ask a question. I'd rather help get your solution to work than just give you one.

Anyway, this one-liner works:

```
echo "\"Hello How are you\" Mr. John \"how are you?\"" | perl -pe's/"[^"]+"/$&=~s! !_!gr/ge'
```

It is a regex within a regex. Here's how it works:

To search and replace all spaces with underscores, we can simply run `s/ /_/g`. However, Perl lets you pick the delimiter you use in the statement. Since I wanted to use `/` in the outer regex, I picked `!` for the inner. That gives us the statement `s! !_!g`. The `g` flag means global, so it will replace all of the spaces with underscores, not just the first one.

The outer regex is this `s/"[^"]+"/{previous regex}/ge`. We are searching for each instances where we have a quote, followed by anything that is not a quote, followed by a quote (`"[^"]"`). The match gets stored in the built-in variable, `$&`. The `e` flag means eval, so the "replace" part of the regex will be treated as code.

Finally, the output is:

```
"Hello_How_are_you" Mr. John "how_are_you?"
```

This works on older Perl versions:

```
cat a | perl -lane 'use English; if( m/"[^"]+"/ ){$p=${PREMATCH};$t=$&;$e=${POSTMATCH}; $t=~s/ /_/g;print "$p$t$e"}'
```

Comment: I try to match the  using $`,$&,$' regx variable. didn't work as I expected, that's why posted this quesstion

Comment: I tried this on  perl, v5.10.1. its giving me the error.      Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "s! !_!gr"
syntax error at -e line 1, near "s! !_!gr"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: I have double quot only once in a line, Now I am using this.  cat a|perl -lane 'if( m/("[^"]+")/g){$p=${^PREMATCH};$t=$&;$e=${^POSTMATCH}; $t=~s/ /_/g;print "$p$t$e"}'

Comment: What shell are you in? You have to escape the single quotes. Try running this: `cat a | perl -lane 'if( m/"[^"]+"/ ){$p=${^PREMATCH};$t=$&;$e=$'\''; $t=~s/ /_/g;print "$p$t$e"}'`

Comment: Oh, you need to `use English` to use the english names for those variables. Try this: `cat a | | perl -lane 'use English; if( m/"[^"]+"/ ){$p=${PREMATCH};$t=$&;$e=${POSTMATCH}; $t=~s/ /_/g;print "$p$t$e"}'`

Answer (score 1):

Another approach: split the string on double quotes. Then the *contents* of the double quotes is every *odd-numbered element* of the resulting array.

```
perl -F'"' -ane '
    for ($i=1; $i<$#F; $i+=2) { $F[$i] =~ s/ /_/g }
    print join q{"}, @F
' <<END
"Hello How are you"  Mr. John. "I am fine."
END
```

```
"Hello_How_are_you"  Mr. John. "I_am_fine."
```